# Inserting Bytes to Postgres with python gives error, but with PG SQL console works

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pycrypto

I'm encrypting some data and trying to insert it into postgres as bytes. I'm using psycopg2 and python. When I try from python it gives me an error about varying character.

Error value too long for type character varying(30)

Entry Exist Passing!

When I insert it into the Postgresql using the exact output of the SQL statement im using in python it will work. I got the statement using the eclipse console window by displaying the variable the statement is stored in. This is the PG Console output:

```
metering=# insert into customers(customer_id,customer_name, inactive, datetime) values (101,'\021;\213D\351O\0339"(($v_\033\262'::bytea,'Y', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT 0 1
                      ^
metering=# select * from customers;
 customer_id |           customer_name            | inactive |  datetime  
-------------+------------------------------------+----------+------------
         101 | \x113b8b44e94f1b3922282824765f1bb2 | Y        | 2014-10-06
(1 row)
```

**Database table definition and database format**

```
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

customer_id bigint NOT NULL,
customer_name bytea NOT NULL,
inactive character varying(1) NOT NULL,
datetime date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT customers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
```

**Errors returned by python**

```
2014-10-16 12:19:23,077 ERROR Error invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xca 0x3c
2014-10-16 12:20:47,796 ERROR Error invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xca 0x3c
```

**Code to insert encrypted customer name.**

```
password = hashlib.sha256(secretmofokey).digest()  
IV = 16 * '\x00'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(password, mode, IV=IV)

      for customer_id, customer_name, inactive in oracle_cursor:
         try:
               encrypted_customer_name = encryptor.encrypt(pad(customer_name))

               pg_delete.execute("""delete from customers where customer_id = %s """ % customer_id)

               customers_sql = ("""insert into customers(customer_id, 
                           customer_name , inactive, datetime) 
                           values (%s, '%s', '%s' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) """ % (customer_id, encrypted_customer_name, inactive))

               pg_insert.execute(customers_sql)
               postgres.commit()

         except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
            logging.error('Error %s' % e)    
            postgres.rollback()
            continue
```

Comment: ... and what's the table definition? Please show `\d customers`. Also show the **exact text** of the error you get from the Python code.

Comment: ok thanks one second.

Comment: @CraigRinger There I added the database format and table definition. I've tried with '%s' and without '%s' and its the same error.

Answer (score 4):

[Per the psycopg2 manual](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-binary), you have to explicitly identify data you want inserted as bytea:

You're also incorrectly trying to quote your format specifiers. You do not need and should not include the single quotes around `%s`; psycopg2 will do the appropriate quoting.

So you want:

```
"""... values (%s, %s, %s , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) """
 % (customer_id, psycopg2.Binary(encrypted_customer_name), inactive)
```